# lftp handling of negative response to ALLO

Tags: ftp, lftp

I'm using lftp 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 20.4 with my own ftpd server code.

As the debug log below shows, in preparation for a transfer lftp sends ALLO but appears to ignore the negative response (452 "no space").

I've also tried a 552 "Exceeded storage allocation" response, which was also ignored.

Is there a more appropriate response? Am I misunderstanding the role of ALLO?

Any and all suggestions welcome!  Thanks.

```
    > put lfs.img -o lfs3
    ---- Connecting to ftpd (192.168.0.171) port 21
    <--- 220 nil                         
    ---> FEAT
    <--- 211-Extensions supported:             
    <---  SIZE
    <---  REST STREAM
    <---  PASV
    <--- 211 END
    ---> USER anonymous
    <--- 331 nil                         
    ---> PASS lftp@
    <--- 230 nil                               
    ---> PWD
    <--- 257 /                                     
    ---> TYPE I
    <--- 200 nil                                   
    ---> PASV
    <--- 227 Entering Passive Mode. 192,168,0,171,255,249
    ---- Connecting data socket to (192.168.0.171) port 65529
    ---- Data connection established
    ---> ALLO 72408
    <--- 452 no space                              
    ---> STOR lfs3
    <--- 500 open fail                             
    ---- Closing data socket
    put: lfs.img: Fatal error: 500 open fail
```

Comment: lftp seems to ignore 4xx responses to `ALLO`. What does the log look like for the 5xx?

Comment: Aha; yes. A 552 response works better.  lftp still sends STOR, but follows that with an ABOR.   And, re-reading rfc 959 I see that an ALLO must always be followed by a STOR or APPE (para 4.1.3), so that is correct behaviour by lftp.

Answer (score 1):

lftp correctly handles a response of 552 ("Requested file action aborted. Exceeded storage allocation") to an ALLO command. lftp responds to the 552 response with a STOR command, immediately followed by an ABOR (ie. Abort) command.

From RFC 959 (para 4.1.3.): "This command [ALLO] shall be followed by a STORe or APPEnd command."   So although the STOR command will not succeed, it would be incorrect to skip it and just send ABOR.